# Mailjet REST API - is it even functional?

Tags: python, mailjet

I'm using the mailjet Python API, and I'm a little confused.

https://www.mailjet.com/docs/api/lists/contacts

It doesn't even appear possible to use this API class to call mailjets GET methods.
Can anyone confirm this is the case?

```
api.lists.Contacts(id='foo') # causes POST, thus 405
```

Here's their API classes. I don't even see `ApiMethodFunction` passing options to the `connection` class.

```
class ApiMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, api, method):
        self.api = api
        self.method = method

    def __getattr__(self, function):
        return ApiMethodFunction(self, function)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.method

class ApiMethodFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, method, function):
        self.method = method
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        response = self.method.api.connection.open(
            self.method,
            self.function,
            postdata=kwargs,
        )
        return json.load(response)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.function
```

It seems like a critical feature so I'm inclined to think I'm just using it incorrectly, but could it be?

How are you supposed to list Contacts if it needs `id` in the GET parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the python library is now fixed. According to its author, you can now pass a parameter to specify if the request is going to be a POST or a GET

https://github.com/WoLpH/mailjet

Comment: Nice find jfoucher! Looks like it was updated just now. Still, it seems completely broken. I will post a new question re pagination.

Comment: well, can we use this python library to do everything we can with boto/SES?  For example, can we add HTML body and trigger a send?